# How I can devide columns of two differnt datarames, while the values in two other coulmns are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have a time-series dataset with different amounts of released gases in each time step as follows, the data is monitored day to day, in Date the sampling time is reflected and in the other columns the amount of released gas.

```py
import pandas as pd
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
Data = pd.read_csv('PTR 69.csv')
Data.columns = ['Date', 'H2', 'CH4', 'C2H6', 'C2H4', 'C2H2', 'CO', 'CO2', 'O2']
Data.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
Data.head()
```

It looks like this:

```py
    Date             H2         CH4         C2H6        C2H4        C2H2     CO          CO2         O2
0   2021-04-14 2:00  8.301259   10.889560  7.205929 3.485577    0.108262    318.616211  1659.179688 866.826721
1   2021-04-13 3:00  8.190150   10.224614  7.369829 3.561115    0.130052    318.895599  1641.014526 883.500305
2   2021-04-12 4:00  8.223248   10.297009  7.571199 3.479434    0.113566    315.364594  1636.670776 896.083679
3   2021-04-11 5:00  8.342580   10.233653  7.726023 3.474085    0.234786    316.315277  1641.205078 875.664856
4   2021-04-10 6:00  8.365788   9.825816   7.640978 3.621368    0.320388    320.200409  1658.575806 880.871399
5   2021-04-09 7:00  8.113251   11.198173  7.588203 3.561790    0.200721    318.738922  1651.639038 886.923401
6   2021-04-08 8:00  7.881397   7.967482   7.382273 3.528960    0.180016    315.252838  1625.236328 878.604309
7   2021-04-07 9:00  7.833044   6.773924   7.292545 3.475330    0.401435    317.085449  1628.325562 893.305664
8   2021-04-06 10:00 7.908926   9.419571   7.018494 3.347562    0.406113    317.643768  1620.742554 912.732422
9   2021-04-05 11:00 8.192807   9.262563   7.227449 3.275920    0.133978    312.931152  1601.240 845 932.079102
10  2021-04-04 12:00 8.086914   9.480316   6.515196 3.312712    0.000000    315.486816  1609.530884 928.141907
11  2021-04-03 13:00 7.984566   9.406860   6.712120 3.476949    0.336859    312.862793  1596.182495 938.904724
12  2021-04-02 14:00 8.077889   8.335327   7.443592 3.605910    0.416443    315.546539  1605.549438 928.619568
13  2021-04-01 15:00 7.996786   9.087573   7.950811 3.626776    0.745824    311.601471  1608.987183 897.747498
14  2021-03-31 16:00 8.433417   10.078784  6.567528 3.646854    0.682301    313.811615  1619.164673 825.123596
15  2021-03-30 17:00 8.445275   9.768773   7.460344 3.712297    0.353539    314.944672  1606.494751 811.027161
16  2021-03-29 18:00 8.398427   9.607062   7.446943 3.674934    0.287205    314.554596  1599.793823 828.780090
17  2021-03-28 19:00 8.272332   9.678397   7.303371 3.617573    0.430137    311.486664  1590.122192 828.557312
18  2021-03-27 20:00 8.478241   9.364383   7.153194 3.616118    0.548547    314.538849  1578.516235 821.565125
19  2021-03-26 21:00 8.452413   10.828227  6.825691 3.260484    0.642971    314.990082  1561.811890 826.468079
```

First I used the [`pd.to_datetime`] and separate the data frame based on the month and year as you can see:

````py
Data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Date'])
# How long is the dataset
Data['Date'].max () - Data['Date'].min ()

Reults:
```python
Timedelta('1364 days 12:49:00')
````

Data['Month'] = Data['Date'].dt.month
Data['Year'] = Data['Date'].dt.year
Data.head()

````
Then like this:
```python
    Date  H2  CH4   C2H6   C2H4  C2H2  CO    CO2      O2      Month     Year
0   2021-04-14 02:00:00 8.301259  10.889560 7.205929 3.485577 0.108262 318.616211 1659.179688 866.826721 4  2021
1   2021-04-13 03:00:00 8.190150  10.224614 7.369829 3.561115 0.130052 318.895599 1641.014526 883.500305 4  2021
2   2021-04-12 04:00:00 8.223248  10.297009 7.571199 3.479434 0.113566 315.364594 1636.670776 896.083679 4  2021
3   2021-04-11 05:00:00 8.342580  10.233653 7.726023 3.474085 0.234786 316.315277 1641.205078 875.664856 4 2021
4   2021-04-10 06:00:00 8.365788  9.825816  7.640978 3.621368 0.320388 320.200409 1658.575806 880.871399 4  2021
5   2021-04-09 07:00:00 8.113251  11.198173 7.588203 3.561790 0.200721 318.738922 1651.639038 886.923401 4  2021
6   2021-04-08 08:00:00 7.881397  7.967482  7.382273 3.528960 0.180016 315.252838 1625.236328 878.604309 4  2021
7   2021-04-07 09:00:00 7.833044  6.773924  7.292545 3.475330 0.401435 317.085449 1628.325562 893.305664 4  2021
8   2021-04-06 10:00:00 7.908926  9.419571  7.018494 3.347562 0.406113 317.643768 1620.742554 912.732422 4  2021
9   2021-04-05 11:00:00 8.192807  9.262563  7.227449 3.275920 0.133978 312.931152 1601.240845 932.079102 4 2021
````

So, two other columns [`Month`] and [`Year`] are added to the data frame.
My question: **How I can calculate the rate of H2 changes over a month?
I know that first, I should calculate the mean of H2 in each month and each year as my data is time-sereis.**

```py
Mean_month = Data.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))['H2'].mean().reset_index()
```

I used the previous steps to convert the date to [`pd.to_datetime`]:

```py
Mean_month['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Mean_month['Date'])
Mean_month['Month_mean'] = Mean_month['Date'].dt.month
Mean_month['Year_mean'] = Mean_month['Date'].dt.year
Mean_month.head ()
```

looks like this one:

```py
Date    H2  CH4 C2H2    C2H4    C2H6    CO  CO2 O2  Month_mean  Year_mean
0   2017-07-31  0.892207    0.797776    0.572518    0.119328    0.203212    23.137884   230.986328  1756.658813 7   2017
1 2017-08-31       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  8   2017
2 2017-09-30       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  9   2017
3 2017-10-31       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  10  2017
4 2017-11-30       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  11  2017
5 2017-12-31       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  12  2017 
6 2018-01-31       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  1   2018
7 2018-02-28       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  2   2018
8 2018-03-31       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN   3   2018
9 2018-04-30       NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  4   2018
10 2018-05-31      NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  5   2018
11 2018-06-30   3.376091    1.780959    0.488345    0.431397    1.777461    59.424690   246.135108  2927.244192 6   2018
12 2018-07-31   3.785872    1.710799    0.479277    0.405084    2.416031    63.220747   256.035651  2971.905932 7   2018
13 2018-08-31   3.789915    1.874313    0.444453    0.339609    2.516580    67.629768   264.437564  3016.440033 8   2018
14 2018-09-30   3.882403    1.842717    0.443967    0.342131    2.848867    71.592693   271.972792  3073.598901 9   2018
15 2018-10-31   3.858354    2.037401    0.364234    0.358209    2.651448    75.036622   274.889362  3150.082060 10  2018
16 2018-11-30   3.861638    1.854492    0.276273    0.289241    2.813399    78.563868   289.631986  3176.243186 11  2018
17 2018-12-31   5.029865    2.526096    0.232814    0.510899    3.423260    95.641880   409.359902  2831.721010 12  2018
18  2019-01-31  6.103601    2.528294    0.177558    0.612607    4.039948    116.639744  516.362618  2423.434258 1   2019
19  2019-02-28  7.480646    3.316433    0.239254    0.959470    5.319684    142.571229  662.409360  1877.447767 2   2019
20  2019-03-31  8.363644    3.779225    0.213011    1.171834    6.179431    167.295488  815.904473  1415.431158 3   2019
21  2019-04-30  9.523452    4.620810    0.233048    1.703750    8.359211    195.914846  1044.554593 898.940531  4   2019
22  2019-05-31  10.118435   5.524447    0.311802    1.904199    9.275237    213.531002  1178.495602 657.617859  5   2019
23  2019-06-30  10.283766   6.186843    0.377420    2.165453    10.729356   226.061226  1226.489872 589.417023  6   2019
24  2019-07-31  9.943331    6.648062    0.492584    2.326774    11.791042   234.309877  1257.822071 572.162592  7   2019
25  2019-08-31  9.812387    6.681962    0.510871    2.483979    13.067311   243.440762  1302.643938 568.994610  8   2019
26  2019-09-30  9.661653    7.323367    0.420726    2.628199    13.308826   252.133648  1383.259943 550.533951  9   2019
27  2019-10-31  9.246261    7.644706    0.372446    2.673924    13.880747   257.093790  1407.996110 565.502500  10  2019
28  2019-11-30  8.226894    6.606762    0.411812    2.290050    12.958136   257.590110  1306.817593 654.086494  11  2019
29  2019-12-31  7.985734    7.461197    0.314830    2.417687    13.255049   259.519881  1309.507549 684.085808  12  2019
30  2020-01-31  7.754674    7.804206    0.336518    2.506526    13.554615   262.188585  1312.052006 700.065050  1   2020
31  2020-02-29  7.662918    7.607357    0.283796    2.483387    13.803671   264.348120  1300.252926 710.281917  2   2020
32  2020-03-31  7.602619    8.326974    0.278294    2.629290    13.983202   268.429411  1351.023144 698.012543  3   2020
33  2020-04-30  7.585870    8.028798    0.389348    2.856049    15.635886   273.859451  1426.279447 703.866225  4   2020
34  2020-05-31  7.752543    8.622809    0.329810    2.974434    16.470193   279.636700  1484.100789 685.164897  5   2020
35  2020-06-30  7.935418    8.632543    0.408732    3.410121    18.330232   287.545439  1593.554077 653.294214  6   2020
36  2020-07-31  8.226212    9.180892    0.474289    3.646311    19.746735   295.059049  1688.793476 613.164837  7   2020
37  2020-08-31  8.535027    9.583940    0.517722    3.860195    20.853958   303.025472  1759.655769 597.264223  8   2020
38  2020-09-30  8.782468    9.318198    0.447619    3.780273    21.613501   309.644693  1790.096266 594.891798  9   2020
39  2020-10-31  8.766880    17.531840   0.436720    3.671641    21.794714   312.511920  1783.446248 622.681765  10  2020
40  2020-11-30  8.535022    9.695740    0.427224    3.352291    11.561881   311.624202  1676.413354 713.680609  11  2020
41  2020-12-31  8.374398    9.114723    0.340198    3.351321    6.768138    312.902290  1642.077442 766.767532  12  2020
42  2021-01-31  8.238818    9.373566    0.344173    3.372903    6.670032    313.475182  1604.747685 788.205679  1   2021
43  2021-02-28  8.191080    9.900578    0.334562    3.352319    6.802692    314.076140  1572.294619 815.143081  2   2021
44  2021-03-31  8.317389    9.627182    0.385551    3.209554    5.862067    312.134351  1484.145511 867.169165  3   2021
45  2021-04-30  8.107043    9.457317    0.266317    3.488106    7.331760    316.181560  1627.434300 900.000397  4   2021
```

As the [`Mean_month`] data frame is sorted ascending, I resorted it again with:

```py
Srt_Mean = Mean_month.sort_values(['Date'],ascending=False)
Srt_Mean
```

the results are:

```py
Date    H2  CH4 C2H2    C2H4    C2H6    CO  CO2 O2  Month_mean  Year_mean
45  2021-04-30  8.107043    9.457317    0.266317    3.488106    7.331760    316.181560  1627.434300 900.000397  4   2021
44  2021-03-31  8.317389    9.627182    0.385551    3.209554    5.862067    312.134351  1484.145511 867.169165  3   2021
43  2021-02-28  8.191080    9.900578    0.334562    3.352319    6.802692    314.076140  1572.294619 815.143081  2   2021
42  2021-01-31  8.238818    9.373566    0.344173    3.372903    6.670032    313.475182  1604.747685 788.205679  1   2021
41  2020-12-31  8.374398    9.114723    0.340198    3.351321    6.768138    312.902290  1642.077442 766.767532  12  2020
40  2020-11-30  8.535022    9.695740    0.427224    3.352291    11.561881   311.624202  1676.413354 713.680609  11  2020
39  2020-10-31  8.766880    17.531840   0.436720    3.671641    21.794714   312.511920  1783.446248 622.681765  10  2020
38  2020-09-30  8.782468    9.318198    0.447619    3.780273    21.613501   309.644693  1790.096266 594.891798  9   2020
37  2020-08-31  8.535027    9.583940    0.517722    3.860195    20.853958   303.025472  1759.655769 597.264223  8   2020
36  2020-07-31  8.226212    9.180892    0.474289    3.646311    19.746735   295.059049  1688.793476 613.164837  7   2020
35  2020-06-30  7.935418    8.632543    0.408732    3.410121    18.330232   287.545439  1593.554077 653.294214  6   2020
34  2020-05-31  7.752543    8.622809    0.329810    2.974434    16.470193   279.636700  1484.100789 685.164897  5   2020
33  2020-04-30  7.585870    8.028798    0.389348    2.856049    15.635886   273.859451  1426.279447 703.866225  4   2020
32  2020-03-31  7.602619    8.326974    0.278294    2.629290    13.983202   268.429411  1351.023144 698.012543  3   2020
31  2020-02-29  7.662918    7.607357    0.283796    2.483387    13.803671   264.348120  1300.252926 710.281917  2   2020
30  2020-01-31  7.754674    7.804206    0.336518    2.506526    13.554615   262.188585  1312.052006 700.065050  1   2020
29  2019-12-31  7.985734    7.461197    0.314830    2.417687    13.255049   259.519881  1309.507549 684.085808  12  2019
28  2019-11-30  8.226894    6.606762    0.411812    2.290050    12.958136   257.590110  1306.817593 654.086494  11  2019
27  2019-10-31  9.246261    7.644706    0.372446    2.673924    13.880747   257.093790  1407.996110 565.502500  10  2019
26  2019-09-30  9.661653    7.323367    0.420726    2.628199    13.308826   252.133648  1383.259943 550.533951  9   2019
25  2019-08-31  9.812387    6.681962    0.510871    2.483979    13.067311   243.440762  1302.643938 568.994610  8   2019
24  2019-07-31  9.943331    6.648062    0.492584    2.326774    11.791042   234.309877  1257.822071 572.162592  7   2019
23  2019-06-30  10.283766   6.186843    0.377420    2.165453    10.729356   226.061226  1226.489872 589.417023  6   2019
22  2019-05-31  10.118435   5.524447    0.311802    1.904199    9.275237    213.531002  1178.495602 657.617859  5   2019
21  2019-04-30  9.523452    4.620810    0.233048    1.703750    8.359211    195.914846  1044.554593 898.940531  4   2019
20  2019-03-31  8.363644    3.779225    0.213011    1.171834    6.179431    167.295488  815.904473  1415.431158 3   2019
19  2019-02-28  7.480646    3.316433    0.239254    0.959470    5.319684    142.571229  662.409360  1877.447767 2   2019
18  2019-01-31  6.103601    2.528294    0.177558    0.612607    4.039948    116.639744  516.362618  2423.434258 1   2019
17  2018-12-31  5.029865    2.526096    0.232814    0.510899    3.423260    95.641880   409.359902  2831.721010 12  2018
16  2018-11-30  3.861638    1.854492    0.276273    0.289241    2.813399    78.563868   289.631986  3176.243186 11  2018
15  2018-10-31  3.858354    2.037401    0.364234    0.358209    2.651448    75.036622   274.889362  3150.082060 10  2018
14  2018-09-30  3.882403    1.842717    0.443967    0.342131    2.848867    71.592693   271.972792  3073.598901 9   2018
13  2018-08-31  3.789915    1.874313    0.444453    0.339609    2.516580    67.629768   264.437564  3016.440033 8   2018
12  2018-07-31  3.785872    1.710799    0.479277    0.405084    2.416031    63.220747   256.035651  2971.905932 7   2018
11  2018-06-30  3.376091    1.780959    0.488345    0.431397    1.777461    59.424690   246.135108  2927.244192 6   2018
10  2018-05-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5   2018
9   2018-04-30  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4   2018
8   2018-03-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3   2018
7   2018-02-28  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2   2018
6   2018-01-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   2018
5   2017-12-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 12  2017
4   2017-11-30  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 11  2017
3   2017-10-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  2017
2   2017-09-30  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9   2017
1   2017-08-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8   2017
0   2017-07-31  0.892207    0.797776    0.572518    0.119328    0.203212    23.137884   230.986328  1756.658813 7   2017
```

I also defined the index for both data frames as finally, I want to divide the column of [`H2`] in the first data frame over the column of [`H2`] in the first dataframe:

```py
df_Data = Data.set_index(['Month', 'Year'])
df_Data.head (50)
df_Srt_Mean = Srt_Mean.set_index (['Month_mean', 'Year_mean'])
df_Srt_Mean.head (50)
```

```py
Date    H2  CH4 C2H6    C2H4    C2H2    CO  CO2 O2
Month   Year                                    
4   2021    2021-04-14 02:00:00 8.301259    10.889560   7.205929    3.485577    0.108262    318.616211  1659.179688 866.826721
    2021    2021-04-13 03:00:00 8.190150    10.224614   7.369829    3.561115    0.130052    318.895599  1641.014526 883.500305
    2021    2021-04-12 04:00:00 8.223248    10.297009   7.571199    3.479434    0.113566    315.364594  1636.670776 896.083679
    2021    2021-04-11 05:00:00 8.342580    10.233653   7.726023    3.474085    0.234786    316.315277  1641.205078 875.664856
    2021    2021-04-10 06:00:00 8.365788    9.825816    7.640978    3.621368    0.320388    320.200409  1658.575806 880.871399
    2021    2021-04-09 07:00:00 8.113251    11.198173   7.588203    3.561790    0.200721    318.738922  1651.639038 886.923401
    2021    2021-04-08 08:00:00 7.881397    7.967482    7.382273    3.528960    0.180016    315.252838  1625.236328 878.604309
    2021    2021-04-07 09:00:00 7.833044    6.773924    7.292545    3.475330    0.401435    317.085449  1628.325562 893.305664
    2021    2021-04-06 10:00:00 7.908926    9.419571    7.018494    3.347562    0.406113    317.643768  1620.742554 912.732422
    2021    2021-04-05 11:00:00 8.192807    9.262563    7.227449    3.275920    0.133978    312.931152  1601.240845 932.079102
    2021    2021-04-04 12:00:00 8.086914    9.480316    6.515196    3.312712    0.000000    315.486816  1609.530884 928.141907
    2021    2021-04-03 13:00:00 7.984566    9.406860    6.712120    3.476949    0.336859    312.862793  1596.182495 938.904724
    2021    2021-04-02 14:00:00 8.077889    8.335327    7.443592    3.605910    0.416443    315.546539  1605.549438 928.619568
    2021    2021-04-01 15:00:00 7.996786    9.087573    7.950811    3.626776    0.745824    311.601471  1608.987183 897.747498
3   2021    2021-03-31 16:00:00 8.433417    10.078784   6.567528    3.646854    0.682301    313.811615  1619.164673 825.123596
    2021    2021-03-30 17:00:00 8.445275    9.768773    7.460344    3.712297    0.353539    314.944672  1606.494751 811.027161
    2021    2021-03-29 18:00:00 8.398427    9.607062    7.446943    3.674934    0.287205    314.554596  1599.793823 828.780090
    2021    2021-03-28 19:00:00 8.272332    9.678397    7.303371    3.617573    0.430137    311.486664  1590.122192 828.557312
    2021    2021-03-27 20:00:00 8.478241    9.364383    7.153194    3.616118    0.548547    314.538849  1578.516235 821.565125
    2021    2021-03-26 21:00:00 8.452413    10.828227   6.825691    3.260484    0.642971    314.990082  1561.811890 826.468079
    2021    2021-03-25 22:00:00 8.420037    10.468951   6.614395    3.279383    0.442519    314.821197  1538.289673 835.261902
    2021    2021-03-24 23:00:00 8.290853    9.943011    5.952219    3.263231    0.077059    313.060883  1498.917969 859.999023
    2021    2021-03-24 00:00:00 8.053485    9.717534    5.773523    3.210894    0.477235    309.256561  1461.547974 867.371643
    2021    2021-03-23 01:00:00 8.813514    10.700623   5.444063    2.965948    0.421797    312.926971  1437.077026 867.363709
    2021    2021-03-22 02:00:00 8.149124    9.727563    4.518490    2.958276    0.368664    311.796661  1420.417358 916.602539
    2021    2021-03-21 03:00:00 8.169525    8.859634    5.212233    3.129839    0.416121    312.702301  1419.987427 904.523865
    2021    2021-03-20 04:00:00 7.999515    8.994797    5.137753    3.148643    0.475540    307.183685  1420.932739 913.971130
    2021    2021-03-19 05:00:00 8.183563    10.373088   4.949068    3.037351    0.584536    312.275482  1440.424683 895.362122
    2021    2021-03-18 06:00:00 9.914630    10.722699   4.891720    3.121366    0.364292    312.476959  1446.715210 889.638367
    2021    2021-03-17 07:00:00 8.063797    9.449814    4.965353    3.158536    0.332817    307.930389  1443.011108 883.420349
    2021    2021-03-16 08:00:00 8.858215    9.454753    5.053194    3.093672    0.249709    313.467071  1456.114624 902.091492
    2021    2021-03-15 09:00:00 8.146770    8.423282    5.213614    3.038460    0.228652    312.719238  1443.799438 900.013672
    2021    2021-03-14 10:00:00 8.160034    14.032947   5.426914    2.981697    0.391028    313.519440  1459.276245 891.870300
    2021    2021-03-13 11:00:00 7.876873    5.985085    5.602545    2.998276    0.607312    311.964203  1447.259399 886.466492
    2021    2021-03-12 12:00:00 8.299830    9.434842    5.768423    2.931913    0.374833    312.165375  1450.703979 893.731873
    2021    2021-03-11 13:00:00 8.258931    9.164996    5.773973    2.917338    0.367790    312.416412  1447.783203 884.459534
    2021    2021-03-10 14:00:00 8.285775    9.396652    5.687450    3.018778    0.367582    312.764160  1452.421875 883.869568
    2021    2021-03-09 15:00:00 8.069007    9.174088    5.641685    3.134619    0.282684    307.792206  1445.247192 887.044922
    2021    2021-03-08 16:00:00 8.150889    8.341151    5.952223    3.310198    0.276260    310.551758  1453.108765 881.680664
    2021    2021-03-07 17:00:00 8.148776    8.571256    5.962189    3.365770    0.321035    311.439789  1450.016235 881.019348
    2021    2021-03-06 18:00:00 8.235992    9.840173    5.190016    3.325249    0.390993    313.732513  1476.067505 880.206055
    2021    2021-03-05 19:00:00 8.041183    8.705338    6.181820    3.528234    0.299884    308.838959  1456.264038 857.722656
    2021    2021-03-04 20:00:00 8.286016    8.883926    5.667931    3.196103    0.350631    314.590729  1479.576538 861.197266
    2021    2021-03-03 21:00:00 8.245660    9.066014    5.785030    3.191303    0.378657    313.044281  1479.022095 850.414856
    2021    2021-03-02 22:00:00 8.386712    9.401718    6.162895    3.043518    0.363813    312.941315  1493.645142 840.161438
    2021    2021-03-01 23:00:00 8.231705    10.864131   6.184435    3.010111    0.217610    309.424164  1501.307983 834.103943
    2021    2021-03-01 00:00:00 8.253326    10.673305   5.977970    3.028328    0.349412    310.304413  1501.962891 825.492371
2   2021    2021-02-28 01:00:00 8.313703    10.718976   5.379131    3.017091    0.303016    313.576935  1511.731079 837.980774
    2021    2021-02-27 02:00:00 8.315781    10.122794   5.632700    3.183661    0.419333    309.140228  1502.215210 855.478516
    2021    2021-02-26 03:00:00 7.974852    10.396459   6.063492    3.239314    0.497979    314.248688  1523.176880 852.766907
```

```py
Date    H2  CH4 C2H2    C2H4    C2H6    CO  CO2 O2
Month_mean  Year_mean                                   
4   2021    2021-04-30  8.107043    9.457317    0.266317    3.488106    7.331760    316.181560  1627.434300 900.000397
3   2021    2021-03-31  8.317389    9.627182    0.385551    3.209554    5.862067    312.134351  1484.145511 867.169165
2   2021    2021-02-28  8.191080    9.900578    0.334562    3.352319    6.802692    314.076140  1572.294619 815.143081
1   2021    2021-01-31  8.238818    9.373566    0.344173    3.372903    6.670032    313.475182  1604.747685 788.205679
12  2020    2020-12-31  8.374398    9.114723    0.340198    3.351321    6.768138    312.902290  1642.077442 766.767532
11  2020    2020-11-30  8.535022    9.695740    0.427224    3.352291    11.561881   311.624202  1676.413354 713.680609
10  2020    2020-10-31  8.766880    17.531840   0.436720    3.671641    21.794714   312.511920  1783.446248 622.681765
9   2020    2020-09-30  8.782468    9.318198    0.447619    3.780273    21.613501   309.644693  1790.096266 594.891798
8   2020    2020-08-31  8.535027    9.583940    0.517722    3.860195    20.853958   303.025472  1759.655769 597.264223
7   2020    2020-07-31  8.226212    9.180892    0.474289    3.646311    19.746735   295.059049  1688.793476 613.164837
6   2020    2020-06-30  7.935418    8.632543    0.408732    3.410121    18.330232   287.545439  1593.554077 653.294214
5   2020    2020-05-31  7.752543    8.622809    0.329810    2.974434    16.470193   279.636700  1484.100789 685.164897
4   2020    2020-04-30  7.585870    8.028798    0.389348    2.856049    15.635886   273.859451  1426.279447 703.866225
3   2020    2020-03-31  7.602619    8.326974    0.278294    2.629290    13.983202   268.429411  1351.023144 698.012543
2   2020    2020-02-29  7.662918    7.607357    0.283796    2.483387    13.803671   264.348120  1300.252926 710.281917
1   2020    2020-01-31  7.754674    7.804206    0.336518    2.506526    13.554615   262.188585  1312.052006 700.065050
12  2019    2019-12-31  7.985734    7.461197    0.314830    2.417687    13.255049   259.519881  1309.507549 684.085808
11  2019    2019-11-30  8.226894    6.606762    0.411812    2.290050    12.958136   257.590110  1306.817593 654.086494
10  2019    2019-10-31  9.246261    7.644706    0.372446    2.673924    13.880747   257.093790  1407.996110 565.502500
9   2019    2019-09-30  9.661653    7.323367    0.420726    2.628199    13.308826   252.133648  1383.259943 550.533951
8   2019    2019-08-31  9.812387    6.681962    0.510871    2.483979    13.067311   243.440762  1302.643938 568.994610
7   2019    2019-07-31  9.943331    6.648062    0.492584    2.326774    11.791042   234.309877  1257.822071 572.162592
6   2019    2019-06-30  10.283766   6.186843    0.377420    2.165453    10.729356   226.061226  1226.489872 589.417023
5   2019    2019-05-31  10.118435   5.524447    0.311802    1.904199    9.275237    213.531002  1178.495602 657.617859
4   2019    2019-04-30  9.523452    4.620810    0.233048    1.703750    8.359211    195.914846  1044.554593 898.940531
3   2019    2019-03-31  8.363644    3.779225    0.213011    1.171834    6.179431    167.295488  815.904473  1415.431158
2   2019    2019-02-28  7.480646    3.316433    0.239254    0.959470    5.319684    142.571229  662.409360  1877.447767
1   2019    2019-01-31  6.103601    2.528294    0.177558    0.612607    4.039948    116.639744  516.362618  2423.434258
12  2018    2018-12-31  5.029865    2.526096    0.232814    0.510899    3.423260    95.641880   409.359902  2831.721010
11  2018    2018-11-30  3.861638    1.854492    0.276273    0.289241    2.813399    78.563868   289.631986  3176.243186
10  2018    2018-10-31  3.858354    2.037401    0.364234    0.358209    2.651448    75.036622   274.889362  3150.082060
9   2018    2018-09-30  3.882403    1.842717    0.443967    0.342131    2.848867    71.592693   271.972792  3073.598901
8   2018    2018-08-31  3.789915    1.874313    0.444453    0.339609    2.516580    67.629768   264.437564  3016.440033
7   2018    2018-07-31  3.785872    1.710799    0.479277    0.405084    2.416031    63.220747   256.035651  2971.905932
6   2018    2018-06-30  3.376091    1.780959    0.488345    0.431397    1.777461    59.424690   246.135108  2927.244192
5   2018    2018-05-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   2018    2018-04-30  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   2018    2018-03-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2018    2018-02-28  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2018    2018-01-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
12  2017    2017-12-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
11  2017    2017-11-30  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10  2017    2017-10-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   2017    2017-09-30  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   2017    2017-08-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   2017    2017-07-31  0.892207    0.797776    0.572518    0.119328    0.203212    23.137884   230.986328  1756.658813
```

Now, for each month of each year, I have one mean, How can divide the column of H2 of the first data frame over this column which includes one number.. For example for
April 2021, we have 30 days and one mean,
May 2021,  we have 31 days and one mean,
Based on the index of these two data frames this division should be performed.

I really appreciate it if if you can help me find a solution..

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and format/edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Jane when you say "divide each column of the first data frame by the number of means (at the same date and year) in the second one", what do you mean by number of means? From your example I believe there will always be only one mean value for each year and month.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..Yeah .. you are right..there is one mean for each month..But I need to divide each individual value (which is day to day..for twice in a day) over the mean.. For example we have 12 months in 2018, meaning we have 12 ,means as well..but the first data frame includes data day to day, which should be divided by these means..
All values in the same month and year should be divided on one mean which is also in the same month and year.